# Double conditional probability

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Is it possible to compute $P(X\mid Y,Z)$ by calculating $P(X\mid Y)$ given the probability $P(\cdot\mid Z)$? Similarly, is it possible to get at the density $f_{X\mid Y,Z}$ by calculating the desity $f_{X\mid Y}$ given $P(\cdot\mid Z)$?

More precisely, let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be a probability space and let $X,Y,Z$ be random variables. Consider the conditional probability induced on $\mathcal{A}$ by conditioning on $Z$: $P(\cdot\mid Z=z)$. Suppose for each $z$ we calculate the conditional distribution $P(X\mid Y=y)$ in the modifed probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P(\cdot\mid Z))$. Is the resulting function of $(y,z)$ equal to the conditional distribution $P(X\mid Y=y, Z=z)$?

Suppose for each $z$ the conditional density $f_{X\mid Y}$ exists given the modified probability space described above. Is the resulting function of $(y,z)$ equal to the conditional density $f_{X\mid Y,Z}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to both questions is: "Yes".

**A Rigorous Statement of the Results to be Proved**

Let $S=\left(\Omega_0,\mathcal{A}_0,P\right)$ be a probability space, let $\left(\Omega_i,\mathcal{A}_i\right)$ be measurable spaces for $i=1,2,3$ and let $X_i$ be $\left(\mathcal{A}_0/\mathcal{A}_i\right)$-measurable functions, respectively. Denote by $P_{X_i}$ $X_i$'s distribution function and by $P_{X_i,X_j}$ $\left(X_i, X_j\right)$'s distribution function ($i,j=1,2,3$) and let $P_*:\Omega_1\times\sigma\left(X_2,X_3\right)\rightarrow\left[0,1\right]$ be a regular version of the conditional distribution $P\left(\left(X_2,X_3\right)\in B_{2,3}\mid X_1=\omega_1\right)$. For every $\omega_1\in\Omega_1$ denote by $P_{\omega_1}$ the probability measure $P_{\omega_1}\left(B_{2,3}\right):=P_*\left(\omega_1,B_{2,3}\right)$.

1. Suppose $Q:\left(\Omega_1\times\Omega_2\right)\times\mathcal{A}_3\rightarrow\left[0,1\right]$ is a function such that for all $B_3\in\mathcal{A}_3$, $Q\left(\cdot,B_3\right)$ is $\left(\mathcal{A}_1\otimes\mathcal{A}_2/\mathfrak{B}\right)$-measurable ($\mathfrak{B}$ being the standard Borel field on the real line). For every $\omega_1\in\Omega_1$ denote by $Q_{\omega_1}$ the function

   $$Q_{\omega_1}:\Omega_2\times\mathcal{A}_3\rightarrow\left[0,1\right],\space\space Q_{\omega_1}\left(\omega_2,B_3\right):=Q\left(\left(\omega_1,\omega_2\right),B_3\right)$$

   and suppose that for every $\omega_1$, $Q_{\omega_1}$ is a version of the conditional distribution $P_{\omega_1}\left(X_3\in B_3\mid X_2=\omega_2\right)$, i.e. the distribution of $X_3$ conditional on $X_2$ given that the underlying probability space is $\left(\Omega_0, \sigma\left(X_2, X_3\right), P_{\omega_1}\right)$.

   Then $Q$ is a version of the conditional distribution $P\left(X_3\in B_3\mid\left(X_1,X_2\right)=\left(\omega_1,\omega_2\right)\right)$.
2. Let $\nu:\mathcal{A}_3\rightarrow\left[0,1\right]$ be some probability measure on $\mathcal{A}_3$. For every $\omega_1\in\Omega_1$ denote by $P_{X_2}^{\left(\omega_1\right)}$ the distribution of $X_2$ given the underlying probability $P_{\omega_1}$.

   Suppose $f:\left(\Omega_1\times\Omega_2\right)\times\Omega_3\rightarrow\left[0,\infty\right)$ is $\left(\left(\mathcal{A}_1\otimes\mathcal{A}_2\right)\otimes\mathcal{A}_3/\mathfrak{B}\right)$-measurable. For every $\omega_1\in\Omega_1$ denote by $f_{\omega_1}$ the function

   $$f_{\omega_1}:\Omega_2\times\Omega_3\rightarrow\left[0,\infty\right),\space\space f_{\omega_1}\left(\omega_2,\omega_3\right):=f\left(\left(\omega_1,\omega_2\right),\omega_3\right)$$

   and suppose that for every $\omega_1\in\Omega_1$, $f_{\omega_1}$ is a $\left(P_{X_2}^{\left(\omega_1\right)}\otimes\nu\right)$-density of $\left(X_2,X_3\right)$ given the underlying probability $P_{\omega_1}$.

   Then $f$ is the $\left(P_{X_1,X_2}\otimes\nu\right)$-density of $\left(\left(X_1,X_2\right),X_3\right)$ given the underlying probability $P$.

   **Comment** Note that a conditional density $f_{X_3\mid X_2}$ w.r.t. $\nu$ is simply a density $f_{X_2,X_3}$ w.r.t. $P_{X_2}\otimes\nu$.

**Proof**

1. Since it is given that $Q$ is $\left(\left(\mathcal{A}_1\otimes\mathcal{A}_2\right)/\mathfrak{B}\right)$-measurable, all that's left to check is that for all $B_3\in\mathcal{A}_3$  and all $B_{1,2}\in\mathcal{A}_1\otimes\mathcal{A}_2$,

   $$\int_{B_{1,2}}Q\left(\omega,B_3\right)\space P_{X_1,X_2}\left(d\omega\right)=P\left(\left(X_1,X_2\right)\in B_{1,2},X_3\in B_3\right)$$

   Fix $B_3\in\mathcal{A}_3$. First assume that $B_{1,2}$ is a rectangle: $B_{1,2}=B_1\times B_2$ for some $B_1\in\mathcal{A}_1,B_2\in\mathcal{A}_2$. Then

   $$\begin{array}{lcl}

   \int_{B_{1,2}}Q\left(\omega,B_3\right)\space P_{X_1,X_2}\left(d\omega\right) & = & \int_{B_1}\int_{B_2}Q\left(\left(\omega_1,\omega_2\right),B_3\right)\space P_{X_2}\left(d\omega_2\right)P_{X_1}\left(d\omega_1\right) \\

   & = & \int_{B_1}\int_{B_2}Q_{\omega_1}\left(\omega_2,B_3\right)\space P_{X_2}\left(d\omega_2\right)P_{X_1}\left(d\omega_1\right) \\

   & = & \int_{B_1}P_{\omega_1}\left(X_2\in B_2,X_3\in B_3\right)P_{X_1}\left(d\omega_1\right) \\

   & = & P\left(X_1\in B_1, X_2\in B_2, X_3\in B_3\right) \\

   & = & P\left(\left(X_1,X_2\right)\in B_{1,2}, X_3\in B_3\right)

   \end{array}$$

   where the first equation is by Tonelli's theorem, the second is by the definition of $Q_{\omega_1}$, the third is by the assumption that $Q_{\omega_1}$ is a conditional distribution and the fourth is by the definition of $P_*$.

   Since these rectangles form a generating $\pi$-system for $\mathcal{A}_1\otimes\mathcal{A}_2$, we can extend the result to all $B_{1,2}\in\mathcal{A}_1\otimes\mathcal{A}_2$ using Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem.
2. Since $f$ is non-negative and $\left(\left(\mathcal{A}_1\otimes\mathcal{A}_2\right)\otimes\mathcal{A}_3/\mathfrak{B}\right)$-measurable, it remains to verify that for all $B_{1,2,3}\in\left(\mathcal{A}_1\otimes\mathcal{A}_2\right)\otimes\mathcal{A}_3$,

   $$\int_{B_{1,2,3}}f\space d\left(P_{X_1,X_2}\otimes\nu\right)=P\left(\left(\left(X_1,X_2\right),X_3\right)\in B_{1,2,3}\right)$$

   First assume that $B_{1,2,3}=\left(B_1\times B_2\right)\times B_3$ for some $B_i\in\mathcal{A}_i$, $i=1,2,3$. Then

   $$
   \begin{array}{lcl}

   \int_{B_{1,2,3}}f\space d\left(P_{X_1,X_2}\otimes\nu\right) & = & \int_{B_1}\int_{B_2}\int_{B_3}f\left(\left(\omega_1,\omega_2\right),\omega_3\right)\space \nu\left(d\omega_3\right)\space P_{X_2}\left(d\omega_2\right)\space P_{X_1}\left(d\omega_1\right) \\

   & = & \int_{B_1}\int_{B_2}\int_{B_3} f_{\omega_1}\left(\omega_2,\omega_3\right)\space\nu\left(d\omega_1\right)\space P_{X_2}\left(d\omega_2\right)\space P_{X_1}\left(d\omega_1\right) \\

   & = & \int_{B_1} P_{\omega_1}\left(X_1\in B_1,X_2\in B_2\right)\space P_{X_1}\left(d\omega_1\right) \\

   & = & P\left(X_1\in B_1, X_2\in B_2, X_3\in B_3\right) \\

   & = & P\left(\left(\left(X_1,X_2\right),X_3\right)\in B_{1,2,3}\right)

   \end{array}
   $$

   where the first equation is by Tonelli's theorem, the second equation is by the definition of $f_{\omega_1}$, the third equation is by the assumption that $f_{\omega_1}$ is a density and the fourth equation is by the definition of $P_{\omega_1}$.

   Using Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem we can extend the result to all $B_{1,2,3}\in\left(\mathcal{A}_1\otimes\mathcal{A}_2\right)\otimes\mathcal{A}_3$.

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 7):

For every $z$, let $Q_z=P(\ \mid Z=z)$, your question is whether for every $(x,y)$,
$$
Q_z(X=x\mid Y=y)=P(X=x\mid Y=y,Z=z).
$$
The answer is "yes", since, by definition,
$$
Q_z(X=x\mid Y=y)=\frac{Q_z(X=x,Y=y)}{Q_z(Y=y)}=\frac{P(X=x,Y=y\mid Z=z)}{P(Y=y\mid Z=z)},
$$
that is,
$$
Q_z(X=x\mid Y=y)=\frac{P(X=x,Y=y, Z=z)}{P(Y=y, Z=z)}=P(X=x\mid Y=y,Z=z).
$$
In particular, if, for every $z$, $f_{X\mid Y}^{(z)}$ is the density of $X$ conditionally on $Y$ with respect to $Q_z$, then $f_{X\mid Y}^{(Z)}$ is the density of $X$ conditionally on $(Y,Z)$.

Comment: Thank you, Did. I understand your answer in the context of discrete probability, but i'm having trouble translating it to a measure theoretic form. The point that i have difficulty with is showing that $Q_z(X=x\mid Y=y)$ is $(Y,Z)$-measureable; alternatively, that if you fix $z$ in the expression $P(X=x\mid Y=y,Z=z)$, you'll get $Q_z(X=x\mid Y=y)$.

Comment: For non discrete probability distributions you will probably run into measurability issues when you will try to collate all the measures $Q_z$.

Comment: I'm keeping this thread open for the time being, hoping i'll have a eureka moment tomorrow and be able to figure out the general case.

Answer (score 1):

$P(X\cap Y\cap Z) = P(X|Y\cap Z)P(Y\cap Z) = P(X|Y\cap Z)P(Y|Z)P(Z)$

So

$P(X|Y\cap Z) = P(X\cap Y\cap Z)/(P(Y|Z)P(Z))$

Can also rearrange to get

$P(X\cap Y\cap Z) = P(Z|X\cap Y)P(X|Y)P(Y)$

So there's your $P(X|Y)$.  Don't know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't get it.

Comment: I put in an edit.  Don't know it you saw it.  I guess my point is that you can find a formula for $P(X|Y\cap Z)$ that does involve $P(X|Y)$ and $P(Z)$, but it's going to involve several other pieces of information too.

Comment: So you're saying the answers to my questions are: No, and your post shows a counter-example of sorts. Do i understand correctly?

Comment: Yes.  Not that my word is final, but that's the way I'm seeing it.  No idea what your background is here, but if you haven't come across Bayes's theorem yet, you will probably help yourself alot by Googling it.