# What is f(x|y|z)?

Tags: conditional-probability

**update:** I find the post on [Double conditional probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364620/double-conditional-probability) @Joe referenced to be useful. But I am still trying to figure out some details.

conditional probability states $$f(A) = \int f(A|z)f(z)dz$$ What happens when $f(A)$ is also a conditional probability? If  $f(A)=f(X|Y)$,  then what is $f(X|Y|Z)$?

Speaking the math in English, $f(X|Y|Z)$  seems to be the probability of $X$ given $Y$ given $Z$. Since $Y$ and $Z$ are given, it seems like saying the probability of $X$ given $Y$ and $Z$, which is $f(X|Y\cap Z)$. But this conclusion feels weird.

To sum up, what is $f(X|Y|Z)$, and how do you represent it with the p.d.f's of $X$, $Y$, $Z$ or their conditional probabilities? (with at most one $|$ notation, since I am having trouble understanding two |s)

Comment: [Double conditional probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364620/double-conditional-probability)

Comment: See also:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927592/conditional-probability-conditioned-twice

Comment: $"f(x|Y|z)"$: I´ve never seen such a notation.  In my opinion it does not make any sense.