# Measurability of $(x,y) \mapsto \mathbb{E}_{(X,Z) \sim \mathbb{P}_{X,Z|Y=y}}[Z|X=x]$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I would like to ask about the measurability of the conditional expectation of $Z$ given $X=x$ calculated on the *conditional* probability measure $\mathbb{P}_{X,Z|Y=y}$.

### Assumptions

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space
and let $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{A})$ and $(\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{B})$ be measurable spaces
such that the existence of a regular conditional distribution is guaranteed (e.g., Euclidean space).
Let $X: \Omega \to \mathcal{X}$, $Y: \Omega \to \mathcal{Y}$ and $Z: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ are random quantities (i.e., measurable mappings)
such that $\mathbb{E}[\lvert Z \rvert] < \infty$.

For each $y \in \mathcal{X}_2$, let $h(x,y) = \mathbb{E}_{(X,Z) \sim \mathbb{P}_{(X,Z)|Y=y}}[Z|X=x]$,
which denote the conditional expectation of $Z$ given $X = x$
calculated in the probability space $(\mathcal{X} \times \mathbb{R}, \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), \mathbb{P}_{X,Z|Y=y})$,
where $\mathbb{P}_{X,Z|Y=y}$ is a (regular) conditional distribution of $(X,Z)$ given $Y=y$.

### My question

**Is the following proposition true?
And if it is true, could you tell me how to show it?**

> $(x,y) \mapsto h(x,y)$ is a $(\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B})$-measurable function.

In [Double conditional probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364620/double-conditional-probability), this proposition is assumed,
but according to the proof of Theorem B.75. (on page 633) of [Theory of Statistics, by Mark J. Schervish](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-4250-5), it is true.

Comment: I think you have asked this question already with another account..

Comment: @Snoop Sorry, it's the same account, but I didn't understand the system well and re-submitted a modified version.