# Product measurability of the Radon-Nikodym derivative of two Marcov kernels

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, radon-nikodym

Let $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{A})$ and $(\mathcal{Y},\mathcal{B})$ are Borel spaces.

Let $\kappa_i: \mathcal{B} \times \mathcal{X} \to [0,1], ~i=1,2$ be Marcov kernels from $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{A})$ to $(\mathcal{Y},\mathcal{B})$,
i.e., for each $B \in \mathcal{B}$, $x \mapsto \kappa_i(B, x)$ is a $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function,
and for each $x \in \mathcal{X}$, $B \mapsto \kappa_i(B, x)$ is a probability measure on $(\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{B})$.

Suppose that for any $x \in \mathcal{X}$, $\kappa_1(\cdot, x) \ll \kappa_2(\cdot, x)$ and
let $f(x,y)$ denote the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d\kappa_1(\cdot, x)}{d\kappa_2(\cdot, x)}(y)$.

**My question**: is it true that $(x,y) \mapsto f(x,y)$ is $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}$-measurable?

I am not familiar with the Marcov kernel, but this question is motivated by that I want to resolve [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4594960/measurability-of-x-y-mapsto-mathbbe-x-z-sim-mathbbp-x-zy-yzx).

Any comments are welcome. Thank you very much.

Comment: RND's are only defined almost everywhere, so you cannot expect  measurability.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you so much for your comment.
What do you mean by "only defined almost everywhere"?
For each $x \in \mathcal{X}$, the RND $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ is $\mathcal{B}$-measurable by definition.